# Where is the House of Representatives forecast on 538?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

On 538 [2016 Election Forecast](http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2016-election-forecast/?ex_cid=rrpromo), there are two tabs: Presidential and Senate election.

Where's their forecast for House of Representatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### They don't.

---

Nate Sliver, founder of FiveThirtyEight, did state [in this chat](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/when-down-ballot-republicans-should-dump-trump/) that it was too rush to create a House forecast:

> **natesilver:** The House model might wind up looking like the Olympic Village in Rio, given how fast we’d have to put it together.

---

To clarify, the Rio Olympic Village [had many problems](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/08/11/sport/athletes-village-rio-olympics-snags/) when it was opened.